# Producing Error code 410 in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, http-status-code-410

I have a dynamic website which generates the product pages dynamically from imported data.
And after few days the product is expired. Now my question is that i want that
the search engine recognize this and removes it from index.

For that i want to create a Template in IIS and want that if a product is no more active then 
coldfusion should generate a 410 Error Code and IIS should call the default 410 template.

How may i implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how to pull in the IIS template, but the first part of your question is fairly easy: Just use the `cfheader` tag.

```
<cfheader statuscode="410" statustext="Gone" />
```

Eric Cobb has [a blog post which provides more detail](http://www.cfgears.com/index.cfm/2009/2/11/Using-cfheader-to-guide-the-Search-Engines).